# Configuring a Silex-Application with paths using Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection

Tags: php, symfony1, dependency-injection, silex

I am currently refactoring a `Silex\Application` that has grown bigger than initially expected. As part of this work I am moving service definitions from the source into a services.yml and just call a `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder` instead. The code looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load(__DIR__ . '/services.yml');
```

Consider the following line of code, which is part of creating a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`:

```
Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array("src/Project/Entity"), true);
```

which looks like this in my services.yml:

```
services:
    doctrine_config:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\Configuration
        factory_class: Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup
        factory_method: createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration
        arguments:
            - [src/Project/Entity]
            - true
```

Finally, my question. I want to pass a key and value to the container builder, which I can access like a parameter, e.g. instead of `[src/Project/Entity]` as first argument for the Doctrine-Setup I want to do something like this: `[%ROOT_PATH%/src/Project/Entity]`, where `%ROOT_PATH%` is added to the ContainerBuilder somewhat like this `$container->???('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__))`.

I found nothing like this in the documentation. I will read through the ContainerBuilder.php to see if I can find something, but I am not sure about the terminology, e.g. whether `%OOT_PATH%` in my scenario is a variable, definition, alias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it myself.

It's as simple as adding:

```
$container->setParameter("ROOT_PATH", dirname(__DIR__));
```

in my snippet above.